# Set a map's top-left and bottom-right coordinates

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I have a fixed number of pushpins on a Bing Map control, and need to set the map's center and zoom level so that I see all pins. In other words, knowing the leftmost, rightmost, topmost and bottommost pins, how can I adjust the view so I see them all?

Is the ZoomLevel value of any significance relative to the scaling/coordinates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming that Points is your collection of Pushpins and map is the name of your map :)

```
var x = from l in Points
        select l.Location;

map.SetView(LocationRect.CreateLocationRect(x));
```